# Bootstrap : Top nav issue with mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap with my wordpress site ,  its perfect when we uploaded to live server but when we hover over/ click nav item in mobile this is what happens [image]

right now if i click on any of the nav items its not clicked and bottom one comes just right to  upper one  , now i don't remember if i modified some css for navigation code while doing this site  but what i expect a single css rule will make it fine   can someone help me to fix this ?

Comment: You need to post your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a minimal, working example. [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

In hover and click some css get overrides which is applied for desktop version.

You have to override desktop version css with media query for mobiles.

Comment: i tried .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a, a:hover{  }   inside media queries but that did not wrk for me @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {}

Comment: @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {..}